# GNU make wildcard variable target

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a makefile with wildcard targets but the wildcards should match on variables.

So I have a makefile like this:

```
A_OUT := bin/a
B_OUT := bin/b

# This does not work
$(%_OUT):
    @echo $@
```

Output:

```
$ make bin/a
make: *** No rule to make target 'bin/a'.  Stop.
```

I can not use `bin/%:`  because the variables may point to another directory.

Is there any way to do this in GNU make?

Comment: Why can't you use `bin/%`? What does the target being a directory change about this? What do you plan on doing in the target that your proposed snippet would do that using `bin/%` doesn't?

Comment: @EtanReisner I wouldn't be able to call it like this: `make A_OUT=anotherdir/a anotherdir/a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a list of targets to all have the same recipe then just list them all in the same rule definition. e.g.

```
$(A_OUT) $(B_OUT):
        @echo $@
```

You can use a variable for that too:

```
A_OUT := bin/a
TGTS += $(A_OUT)
B_OUT := bin/b
TGTS += $(B_OUT)

$(TGTS):
        @echo $@
```

Depending on what you need you may also want to use [Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage)

```
$(TGTS) : bin/% : 
        @echo $@ : $*
```